# My htaccess not working in my website but working in testing site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Finally, I managed to write htaccess code and tested it in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and found its correct.

The way the URL is rewritten in this http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ is working

but when I use the same htaccess code in my website is not working.

new URL http://192.168.1.190/qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/login.php
Actual URL http://192.168.1.190/qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/login

Htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/([^/]*)\.php$ /qjyii2/yii2dev3/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/$1 [L]
```

My mod_rewrite is working fine in server. I did put this htaccess under /www/qjyii2/yii2dev3/ and its not working. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're placing this in `/www/qjyii2/yii2dev3/.htaccess` then use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/qjyii2/yii2dev3/

RewriteRule ^(frontend/web)/([^/]*)\.php$ $1/index.php?r=site/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the **current directory path** from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.